# Why ID is not defined (ejs)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```js
let id = getUrlVars()["id"];
console.log('<%= db.set("tovar"+id, { name: 1 } ) %>')
```

i can't understand why i get this error? (id is not defined)

P.S. i'm noob)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think the first line should pass the ["id"] should be passed inside the brackets, like `getUrlVars(["id"])` or perhaps even `getUrlVars("id")` - it depends on what parameters the function expects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id is define on client side, you're tring to use it in ejs but your server first process the ejs, then send it to your browser, and only then your browser process the client side script.

Your EJS is always processed before client side javascript, when processing ejs only ejs content is defined, your client side script is not yet defined